# Clear result with insertAdjecentHTML or other method?

Tags: html, insertadjacenthtml

I'm requesting data from a wheather API and I need to display the result to a table. I have to user inserAdjacentHTML or other DOM method to add the markup to my div. The problem I have is that for every request it, as expected, adds a new table. But I want to clear the results to display the new data. Now I cant use innerHTML = '' to the element because it's first created in the insertAdjacentHTML. Is there a solution to somehow replace, clear the markup that is added to the DOM?

Comment: *"Now I cant use innerHTML = '' to the element because it's first created in the insertAdjacentHTML... "* I don;t understand that reason...that's like saying, *"I can't use this hammer to remove these nails because a nail gun was used first...?"*

Comment: Anyways, please read on how to post a [mcve]